# How to perform a calculation and it execute only if there are minimum 3 values in the column?

Tags: spotfire, tibco, calculation

[image]I tried few options but I was not getting the correct output, so I am re- posting this question again.

I want to perform a calculation and it should execute only if there are minimum 3 values in the column.

The calculation should execute only if there are minimum 3 values in each column, if there are no 3 values for eg: for Project 1 - Period 1 we don't have any previous value so it should terminate. For period 2 we have only 2 values so it should terminate. Since for period 3 we have minimum 3 values it should execute the calculation `sum(*last 3 values*)`.

The final output should be the `sum(HC)/ SUM(Time)`.

Please see attached image for the data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With respect to if there are 3 values available, if you want the sum of the last 3 HC / sum of the last 3 Time, you can use:

```
if((If(Min(If([HC] is null,-1,[HC])) over (Intersect([Project],LastPeriods(3,[Period])))=-1,0,1))=1,Sum([HC]) over (Intersect([Project],LastPeriods(3,[Period]))) / Sum([Time]) over (Intersect([Project],LastPeriods(3,[Period]))))
```

If you want the sum of the last 3 HC / the time for that row, then:

```
if((If(Min(If([HC] is null,-1,[HC])) over (Intersect([Project],LastPeriods(3,[Period])))=-1,0,1))=1,Sum([HC]) over (Intersect([Project],LastPeriods(3,[Period]))) / [Time])
```

Note, this is grouping it based off Project. If you need it grouped by Project, Task, Sub Task then there will need to be logic in the intersect. Also, the order of your data was determined by the Period column.

Comment: Hi Scsimon, this is where i find the same issue again. I created a calculated column using on the first formula you have given and it is giving me the sum of last 3 HC. What I am actually looking is there should be a calculation whenever there are 3 values. So if you see period 1 there are no previous value, so the calculation should not execute. for period 2 there is only 1 previous value so the calculation again should not execute. for period 3 since there are 3 prior values the calculation should execute

Comment: That's what happens here and that's why you get NULL values for those rows.

Comment: @bulb how did this not answer your question?

Comment: Hi Scsimon, i have added one more image based on the formula you have given. When i used those formula for project 1 subtask 1, period 1 & 2 we are getting the values. For period 1 there are no pervious values so it should give null. for period 2 we have only 2 values so even for that the value is null.

Comment: let me know if you are able to view the second image

Comment: if possible could you please give me your emailid. I can send you the dxp file and show where it is going wrong. Thanks

Comment: You are placing that in a cross table @BULB and that is not what you originally posted. This formula is to be viewed in a standard table display.